# FTPWebRequest .NET 3.5 vs 4

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have an application that does an FTP connection to an IBM mainframe and all has been working fine.  I then recompiled against .NET 4 and the mainframe no longer accepts the file giving me an error message stating either the file doesn't exist, or I don't have permission for it.

This is what I use to send the file:

```
Ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(FtpAddress + "%2F'" + "EM.MOM.FIMSDATA" + ".AA." + "RR(+1)" + "'");
```

Has Microsoft changed anything between .NET 3.5 and 4 because this points to a framework change?

Comment: I know for sure that the FTP framework was changed as there was a bug with active ftp in 3.5 which was fixed in 4.0. Are you working passive or active?

Comment: UsePassive = true; UseBinary = false;

Comment: Is there any documentation on the differences in this class between versions?

Comment: I know it's an old question, but for future visitors, the answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15666976/55209). There is a C# code in the linked KB article.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on Microsoft.

> The cause of this issue is due to a behavior change in the
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest class in .Net Framework 4. There has been a
>   change made to the System.Net.FtpWebRequest class from .Net Framework
>   3.5 to .Net Framework 4 to streamline the use of the CWD protocol commands. The new implementation of the System.Net.FtpWebRequest class
>   prevents the send of extra CWD commands before issuing the actual
>   command which the user requested and instead directly sends the
>   requested command. For fully RFC compliant FTP servers, this should
>   not be an issue, however for non-fully RFC compliant servers, you will
>   see these types of errors.

Solution is on:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2134299