# F# FTP Fails where C# Succeeds

Tags: ftp, f#

I've an application written in C# (.Net 3.5) with this code.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;

string strURI = String.Format("ftp://x{0}ftp/%2F'{1}'", parm1, parm2);
FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(strURI);
ftp.Proxy = null;
ftp.KeepAlive = true;
ftp.UsePassive = false;
ftp.UseBinary = false;
ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("uid", "pass");
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();
...
```

I've translated this into F# (.Net 4.0) to use in my application.

```
open System.Net

let uri = sprintf "ftp://x%sftp/%%2F'%s'" parm1 parm2
let ftp = FtpWebRequest.Create(uri) :?> FtpWebRequest
ftp.Credentials <- new NetworkCredential("uid", "pass")
ftp.Method <- WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
ftp.Proxy <- null
let response = ftp.GetResponse() :?> FtpWebResponse
...
```

At this point, FSI complains.

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g. file not found, no access).

Yet the C# application runs and successfully downloads the file. What am I missing in F# (besides the properties that aren't there in 4.0, i.e. KeepAlive, UsePassive, and UseBinary)?

Comment: Why do you believe the extra properties of `FtpWebRequest` are missing? They are [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest_properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): `ftp.KeepAlive <- true;
ftp.UsePassive <- false;
ftp.UseBinary <- false`

Comment: Okay. I swear, I checked IntelliSense three times over the span of two hours, and these properties never showed up. Now they do. BUT: they don't make a difference. I get the same error.

Comment: Then it makes sense looking at [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251169/ftpwebrequest-net-3-5-vs-4) as you use active ftp mode. I'd check really quick that your C# is OK under .net 4.0 prior to suspecting F# of anything wrong.

Comment: Need more detail to help you with this.  The code you posted will not work under the FSI.  You need to give us the definition of parm1 and parm2 because chances are your issue has something to do with the string you get for uri.

Comment: @Gene Belitski, since the C# project is not mine and it's far more complex than my F# project, I converted my F# project to .Net 3.5 to see if it would run. Same error.

Comment: @Gene Belitski, I coded up a simple C# console application in 4.0 to do the FTP download. Same error. Switched to 3.5, and it downloaded. Now why won't F# and .Net 3.5 download it? I hate giving up on F#, but it seems like that's the answer for this problem. Shell out to my C# app from my F# app to do the download. :(

Comment: @JeffManer: I assume that by saying _I converted my F# project to .Net 3.5_ you meant making an F# console application having target framework 3.5 and you can confirm that the statement  `printfn "%s" (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ImageRuntimeVersion)`
being placed in the beginning of your F# code would output **v2.0.50727**. If this assumption is correct then I'd be puzzled as there is nothing F#-specific in your revealed code. Otherwise your conversion (e.g. continuing using FSI) is not equivalent to C# 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code may have errors, I don't have F# compiler right now.

```
open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Net

let switch_to_legacy_mode _ =
  let wtype = typeof<FtpWebRequest>
  let mfield = wtype.GetField("m_MethodInfo", BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance)
  let mtype = mfield.FieldType
  let knfield = mtype.GetField("KnownMethodInfo", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic)
  let knarr = knfield.GetValue(null) :?> Array
  let flags = mtype.GetField("Flags", BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance)
  let flag_val = 0x100
  for f in knarr do
    let mutable ff = flags.GetValue(f) :?> int
    ff <- ff ||| flag_val
    flags.SetValue(f, ff)

let uri = sprintf "ftp://x%sftp/%%2F'%s'" parm1 parm2
do switch_to_legacy_mode () // Call it once before making first FTP request
let ftp = FtpWebRequest.Create(uri) :?> FtpWebRequest
ftp.Credentials <- new NetworkCredential("uid", "pass")
ftp.Method <- WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
ftp.Proxy <- null
let response = ftp.GetResponse() :?> FtpWebResponse
```

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2134299

> The cause of this issue is due to a behavior change in the
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest class in .Net Framework 4. There has been a
>   change made to the System.Net.FtpWebRequest class from .Net Framework
>   3.5 to .Net Framework 4 to streamline the use of the CWD protocol commands. The new implementation of the System.Net.FtpWebRequest class
>   prevents the send of extra CWD commands before issuing the actual
>   command which the user requested and instead directly sends the
>   requested command. For fully RFC compliant FTP servers, this should
>   not be an issue, however for non-fully RFC compliant servers, you will
>   see these types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
open System
open System.Net

let parm1 = "test"
let parm2 = "othertest"

let uri = String.Format("ftp://x{0}ftp/%2F'{1}'", parm1, parm2)
let ftp = FtpWebRequest.Create(uri) :?> FtpWebRequest;;
```

I had to add a dummy parm1 and parm2 but I'm assuming you've got parm1 and parm2 defined in your actual code. I'd guess that whatever the issue is, it lies in the uri string.  That is, I think you'll find the problem by comparing uri to the known to be good uri string.

Comment: I have indeed compared the uri strings from F# and C#, and they are identical. I would post the uri strings, but I think my company would get mad at me for posting them. That's why I've left the parms undefined, and their real names changed. In my code, their values are set via a config file.

Comment: I have also tried System.String.Format() as you suggested, resulting in the same (correct) uri, and the same error.